Can you recognize the actress?
I'm trying to find the movie where this is from, so if you know the movie/TV-show, I would appreciate if you could help. 
In the video it suggests the woman has some sort of mind control capability. Very sci-fi genre, possibly a TV show. I have tried a lot of image search engines but none of them have worked. 
Character information from the video

Hair colour: Blonde
Special abilities: Eyes used to control people
How powers are gained: Transfer machine/ device
Character type: Villain

Estimated year: late 90's early 2000's
Genre: Sci fi
Language: English/ American
Region: America
Estimated format: Live action TV episode




@John eshel You could ask who posted the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXMb4htQWEo

The show is called "Birds of Prey" and is based in the DC universe: 

Birds of Prey is a television drama series produced in 2002. The
  series was developed by Laeta Kalogridis for The WB and is loosely
  based on the DC Comics series of the same name. The series takes place
  in a Gotham City abandoned by Batman. Despite the series debut
  garnering ratings of 7.6 million viewers (at the time, the network's
  largest premiere in the 18–34 demographic), the series was canceled
  after ratings fell sharply in subsequent weeks. Thirteen episodes were
  produced in total.

The actress in question plays Harley Quinn and her name is "Mia Sara" - you may recognise her from Ferris Bueller's Day Off.
The video is from the episode "Devils Eyes"

Having discovered details about another character, Harley Quinn uses a machine  that gives her metahuman hypnotic powers.

More details on the episode including spoilers:

 She then hypnotizes Helena and persuades her to knock Barbara 
 unconscious and steal an access
 disk. Barbara recovers and uses her subneural device to enable her to
 stand and fight Helena, eventually neutralizing the trance. But Harley
 uses the disk to gain complete control of the clock tower and, after
 killing Wade, she broadcasts the hypnotic signal to every television
 set in New Gotham. Working together with Alfred, Dinah, and Reese,
 Helena must infiltrate the clock tower and battle Harley and her
 cohorts before they gain control of the entire city. It is hinted that
 Bruce Wayne/Batman is probably still alive, as just before the end
 credits, Alfred speaks to "Master Bruce" on the phone at Wayne Manor,
 talking about his daughter Helena and that he would be proud of her.

